# Выбор региона WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Как сделать на сайте Wordpress выбор региона, ну типа "Какой ваш город" и чтобы далее в зависимости от города менялась информация на сайте, подскажите пж, хоть что-нибудь, может плагин какой есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей юзаю этот плагин [WT GeoTargeting](http://web-technology.biz/cms-wordpress/plugin-wt-geotargeting/)